# Refreshing the memory : Notations

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, matching-theory

Can anyone please tell me what does the **1n1, 1n2** mean ?

[image]

Is it a one-hot vector of size n1, n2 or it's just a random vector of that size ?

Thank you

Comment: but X is not a square matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a vector of all ones, of size $n_1 \times 1$ or $n_2 \times 1$.  In summation notation, the two constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n_2} X_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n_1\}$} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} X_{i,j} &\le 1 &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,n_2\}$}
\end{align}